# LINQ to SQL lambda not clear

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to learn webAPI and in the process seeing this below snippet of LINQ.

```
var lastQuestionId = await this.db.TriviaAnswers
            .Where(a => a.UserId == userId)
            .GroupBy(a => a.QuestionId)
            .Select(g => new { QuestionId = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
            .OrderByDescending(q => new { q.Count, QuestionId = q.QuestionId })
            .Select(q => q.QuestionId)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

I know SQL very well but not able to understand the below expressions. Why is new keyword used here? And what is the purpose of matching g.Key with QuestionId ?

```
.Select(g => new { QuestionId = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
            .OrderByDescending(q => new { q.Count, QuestionId = q.QuestionId })
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the query is doing is Projecting an Anonymous Type.The select clause projects an anonymous type. Anonymous types allow you to define a class, then declare and initialize an object of that class, without giving the class a name.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387028.aspx

You mainly do this to retrieve only the results you want back from the query. More like saying Select name, address from person instead of Select * from person

The new keyword has created an anonymous type it has two properties QuestionId and Count. You are assigning the QuestionId and Count with g.Key and g.Count()

Answer (score 0):

`Select()` transforms data into a new form and due to the nature of C# everything is OOP, also LINQ to SQL, thus you need to write `new {} to` create a new object which can contain multiple values.

The `OrderByDescending()` call looks strange, normally you return the sort key with this call.

Answer (score 0):

`Select` makes a transformation on the existing list (enumeration to be precise) of objects. The result is a list of new objects - of anonymous class in your case (if you would transform it to another class of desired type you'd write `.Select(g => new MyClass { QuestionId = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }`). So you have to call the call the constructor of this class - you do it with `new` keyword.
This new anonymous class has two properties (they're crated implicitly) : `QuestionId` and `Count`. You simply assign a value to both of them.

Answer (score 0):

OrderBy method looks this way. keySelector is method gets element of `T` type and return element `K` type.

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T, K>( 
          this IEnumerable<T> source, 
          Func<T, K> keySelector)
    where 
          К : IComparable<K>;
```

Abd the `select` new clause creates an anonymous type instance based entered on array.

Answer (score 0):

The code `new { QuestionId = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })` isn't *matching* `QuestionId` with `g.Key` - it's creating a new anonymous object with the properties `QuestionId` and `Count`.

It is getting the value for `QuestionId` from `g.Key` and the value for `Count` from `g.Count()`.